# How to save changes in .env file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I use `dotenv` for read environment variable. like this:

```
let dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' });
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST);
```

Now I wanna to save changes in `.env` file. I can't find any way to save variable in `.env` file. What should I do?

```
process.env.DB_HOST = '192.168.1.62';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.env file

```
VAR1=var1Value
VAR_2=var2Value
```

index.js file

```
    const fs = require('fs') 
    const envfile = require('envfile')
    const sourcePath = '.env'
    console.log(envfile.parseFileSync(sourcePath))
    let parsedFile = envfile.parseFileSync(sourcePath);
    parsedFile.NEW_VAR = 'newVariableValue'
    fs.writeFileSync('./.env', envfile.stringifySync(parsedFile)) 
    console.log(envfile.stringifySync(parsedFile))
```

final .env file
install required modules and execute index.js file

```
VAR1=var1Value
VAR_2=var2Value
NEW_VAR=newVariableValue
```

Comment: This does not work. Exported functions from `envfile` are `parse` and `stringify` (there is no sync versions.) Also, `parse` requires file contents, ie. it doesn't read the file by itself.

Comment: this actually works if you are working on same process and on same task. if there are multiple tasks running in parallel or sequential process new env vars values will not be considered.

Answer (score 10):

## Update : August 2021

### No external dependency

I was looking for similar solution to read and write key/value to .env file. I read other solutions and have written the 2 functions `getEnvValue` and `setEnvValue` to simplify read/write operations.

To use `getEnvValue`, the .env file should be formatted like the following (i.e. no spaces around `=` sign):

```
KEY_1="value 1"
KEY_2="value 2"
```

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");

const envFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, ".env");

// read .env file & convert to array
const readEnvVars = () => fs.readFileSync(envFilePath, "utf-8").split(os.EOL);

/**
 * Finds the key in .env files and returns the corresponding value
 *
 * @param {string} key Key to find
 * @returns {string|null} Value of the key
 */
const getEnvValue = (key) => {
  // find the line that contains the key (exact match)
  const matchedLine = readEnvVars().find((line) => line.split("=")[0] === key);
  // split the line (delimiter is '=') and return the item at index 2
  return matchedLine !== undefined ? matchedLine.split("=")[1] : null;
};

/**
 * Updates value for existing key or creates a new key=value line
 *
 * This function is a modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001580/3153583
 *
 * @param {string} key Key to update/insert
 * @param {string} value Value to update/insert
 */
const setEnvValue = (key, value) => {
  const envVars = readEnvVars();
  const targetLine = envVars.find((line) => line.split("=")[0] === key);
  if (targetLine !== undefined) {
    // update existing line
    const targetLineIndex = envVars.indexOf(targetLine);
    // replace the key/value with the new value
    envVars.splice(targetLineIndex, 1, `${key}="${value}"`);
  } else {
    // create new key value
    envVars.push(`${key}="${value}"`);
  }
  // write everything back to the file system
  fs.writeFileSync(envFilePath, envVars.join(os.EOL));
};

// examples
console.log(getEnvValue('KEY_1'));
setEnvValue('KEY_1', 'value 1')
```

Comment: I mean that's cool but to me why reinvent the wheel? "Standing on the shoulders of giants" and all that

Comment: @Codebling Your argument is valid for most cases. But i had a very specific requirement and had to create these helper functions. This could be useful for someone who (for some reasons) doesn't want to use an external module like dotenv.

Comment: That's very fair!

Comment: I recommend changing to account for if .env doesn't exist
```
export const readEnvVars = () => {
  try {
    return fs.readFileSync(envFilePath, "utf-8").split(os.EOL);
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
}

```

Comment: @Pencilcheck You can do that. But, my opinion in that case would be that if .env file does not exist, it's a much larger issue and this script should definitely throw an error and fail.

Answer (score 7):

## Do not save data to a `.env` file.

### What is a `.env` file?

'env' stands for [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). Environment variables are shell-based key-value pairs that provide configuration to running applications.

`.env` file is meant to provide easy mechanism for setting these environment variables ***during development*** (usually because a developer machine is constantly being restarted, has multiple shells open, and a developer must switch between projects requiring different environment variables). In production, these parameters will typically be passed by actual environment variables (which, in a cloud configuration, are often easier to manage than file-based solutions, and prevent any secrets from being saved on disk)

### Why can't you modify environment variables?

Environment variables can be modified at the command line, but once a running process is started, it can't/won't affect the parent process' environment variables. If your program exits and restarts, the changes will be lost.

### Why can't you modify a `.env` file?

If you set a value in the `.env` file, it will be used only if an environment variable of the same name does not already exist. If it does, the value of that variable in `.env` file won't be loaded.

Additionally, any changes to written to the `.env` file won't be reflected in your application when reading `process.env` until the application is restarted.

## Use a config file instead

A config file is just a regular file containing configuration. It's like a `.env` file, but it doesn't represent environment variables. It's safe to change it, and safe to use in production.

Comment: The question is how to save an env file, not best practices for using env files. There's valid reasons to generate env files from code such as bootstrapping development environments.

Comment: @AndyBaird you're absolutely right and that is a valid use case, in which case see the other answers. It's fairly clear from the code snippet that OP is not trying to the scenario you describe, so for OP and for newbies arriving from the search engines, I think it's worth mentioning that modifying env files will likely cause issues down the road for many people. See also Meta discussion on [Is "Don't do it" a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: The example in op's question is 3 lines of code. I don't think that's enough to make assumptions about what the code is doing. I only added my comment because I got here through a google search (and I have a valid reason for saving an env file) and this was an entirely unhelpful response to a straightforward question.

Answer (score 4):

## Update : March 2022 - Typescript Example

Please see **@Codebling** post regarding why you should **NOT** do this, however you may be using this as some form of testing. whatever the use case see below.

Using the library [envfile](https://github.com/bevry/envfile)

> Install package: `npm i envfile`
>
> OR as dev dependency: `npm i envfile --save-dev`

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { readFile, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as envfile from 'envfile';

export const writeEnvToFile = (
  envVariables: { key: string; value: any }[],
): void => {
  // get `.env` from path of current directory
  const path = resolve(__dirname, '../../.env');
  readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    const parsedFile = envfile.parse(data);
    envVariables.forEach((envVar: { key: string; value: any }) => {
      if (envVar.key && envVar.value) {
        parsedFile[envVar.key] = envVar.value;
      }
    });
    writeFileSync(path, envfile.stringify(parsedFile));

    // NB: You should now be able to see your .env with the new values,
    // also note that any comments or newlines will be stripped from 
    // your .env after the writeFileSync, but all your pre-existing
    // vars should still appear the .env.

    console.log('Updated .env: ', parsedFile);
  });
};
```

> **Example usage**

```
  writeEnvToFile([
    {
      key: 'YOUR_NEW_ENV_VAR',
      value: 'SOME_VALUE',
    },
    {
      key: 'FOO',
      value: 'BAR',
    },
    {
      key: 'TIME_STAMP',
      value: 1647934964293,
    },
  ]);
```

> **.env BEFORE write**

```
# Some comments about API KEY
API_KEY=xxxabc
```

> **.env AFTER write**

```
API_KEY=xxxabc
YOUR_NEW_ENV_VAR=SOME_VALUE
FOO= BAR
TIME_STAMP=1647934964293
```

Comment: Yeah but the comments are now gone

Answer (score 2):

I solve problem with `envfile` module:

```
const envfile = require('envfile');
const sourcePath = '../../.env';
let sourceObject = {};
// Parse an envfile path
// async
envfile.parseFile(sourcePath, function (err, obj) {
  //console.log(err, obj)
  sourceObject = obj;
  sourceObject.DB_HOST = '192.168.1.62';

  envfile.stringify(sourceObject, function (err, str) {
      console.log( str);
      fs.writeFile(sourcePath, str, function(err) {
          if(err) {
              return console.log(err);
          }

          console.log("The file was saved!");
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: what version of envfile are you using?

Comment: @Carlos, This post was old. I don't remember