# nodejs: how to run tests and then build dockerfile

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to create a basic CI CD Pipeline, I am trying to create batch file to run tests and then execute the docker build. here is my basic batch file

```html
@ECHO OFF
call npm run test
call docker build -t my-docker-file .
PAUSE
```

how can I know if all the tests were run successfully? I am using mocha and chai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to use `--exit` flag to execute your tests. My package.json looks like this:

```json
"test": "mocha test --timeout 4000  --exit"
```

So the console will not stuck open when the tests finish.

Then, the idea is create a communication between batch and node. I've used bash but the idea is the same.

Basically is write in the .env file if tests has been passed and after the execution check if variable is set to true or not.

First of all, to do this you need to update your `test.js` file with this.

I use `envfile`. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360535/how-to-save-changes-in-env-file-in-node-js)

```sh
//get the reference to your environment file and update

//THIS is you have to add
afterEach(function () {
    const state = this.currentTest.state;
    if (state !== "passed") {
        //write into .env: MYENVVAR=0
    }
});
```

Then, you will have into your `.env` file a variable to know if the tests has been executed correctly.

So, the next step is read the value in your batch process and continue if is ok.