# How to automate CI/CD pipeline unit tests for a node.js container deployment in kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, kubernetes, cicd

I am trying to automate unit testing before deploying a node.js container to a local kubernetes cluster. It is not clear to me whether or not I need to configure this in my `deployment.yaml`, `Dockerfile`, `package.json`, or some combination of them. And once configured how to instruct Kubernetes to output any failures and exit before deploying.

Do I need to do as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64655551/1551027) suggests and write a shell script and modify environment variables? Or, is this something I can automate with Kubernetes `deployment.yaml`

If it's useful, I am using `mocha` with `chai`. And this is being deployed from Google Cloud Source Repositories to a local Kubernetes instance.

Since I'm entirely new to Kubernetes, it would be great to have as much detail as possible.

Here is my `deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-container
          image: my-app-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use base node 18-alpine image from Docker hub
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /MY_APP

# Copy package.json and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copy rest of the application source code
COPY . .

# Run index.js
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "test": "npm install mocha -g && mocha --timeout 4000 --exit"
   }
```

And here is a basic unit test I'm using to experiment with:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai'

describe('Basic unit test', ()=>{
    it('Checks if 3*3=9', () => {

        expect(3*3, 9)
    })
})
```

Comment: If you have CI/CD pipeline, then you configure it in the pipeline. This would be GitHub Actions/Workflows if you're using GitHub

Comment: You'll want to run the unit tests first, then build and push your Docker container, then update your Kubernetes deployment to use the new version

Comment: @Codebling I'm using Google Cloud Source Code Repository, and will ultimately be using Google's Kubernetes engine. For now I'm only deploying locally. Can you point me in the right direction for how to do something similar to GitHub Actions/Workflows in GCP?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how CI/CD pipelines work on there. But basically the concept is the same across all platforms, you have a script and as soon as new code appears, it tests it. If that's successful, it builds it. If that's successful, you optionally deploy it (whether you autodeploy depends on your view/policy, some places like to only autodeploy official versions or not autodeploy at all, some places like to deploy every version of master)

Comment: I have a call with my director who knows how to set up CICD on GCP. I'll post the answer here when I understand.

Comment: Sweet, tag me in a comment when you do

Comment: recently we explore k6 for this purpose, https://k6.io/

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I've moved away from Node.js for what I'm working on and ported everything to python. Let me take a look at my old code / configuration for automated unit tests. I'll post an answer if I can locate it for the node project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was a misunderstanding about how the CI/CD pipeline works when it comes to tests.

It goes like this:
`Commit > Build (dev) > Deploy (dev) > Run tests > (pass or fail) > (if pass) promote to production commit > ... deploy`.

If the dev deploy fails the tests, the code is never committed, therefore never moves forward in the pipeline.

In my case, my `package.json` file needed this:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "test": "npm install mocha -g && mocha --timeout 4000 --exit",
    "build": "docker image build -f ./Dockerfile -t my_project:dev ."
  },
```

My `cloudbuild.json` file needed this:

```yaml
- id: "Run unit tests"
  name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["test"]
- id: "run"
  name: node
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ["start"]
```

If the tests pass, the deploy proceeds, otherwise the build fails.

Comment: @codebling answer

Comment: @sai-chandra-gadde answer