# How nodejs reads and writes .env files？

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to read and write env files?

Original file：

```
# I am a note ...
key1=value1

key2=value2
   # I am a note ...
```

I need a function `setEnv(key, value)`.

run `setEnv('key1', 'value2')`， Let it become：

```
# I am a note ...
key1=value2

key2=value2
   # I am a note ...
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: all you need to do is literally split each line on the first `=` and write the raw value to it. there is no such thing as escaping in .env files.
i see no reason in editing the files with node tho. for reading i usually use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 3):

Lets start by creating new project.

```
mkdir folder_name
cd folder_name
npm init
```

Then in your project directory install 'envfile' and 'dotenv'.
Command for installing envfile is

```
npm install envfile --save
```

Similarly install dotenv

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

package dotenv directly reads .env file
package envfile is used to parse and stringify the file as required.
Create `.env` file in the project directory with your details.

```
# I am a note ...
key1=value1

key2=value2
   # I am a note ...
```

Create a new file with `filename.js`

After that for getting and setting env variables you can use following code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config()
const {
    parse,
    stringify
} = require('envfile');
const pathToenvFile = '.env';

/**
 * 
 * @param {string} key 
 * //Function to get value from env
 */
function getEnv(key) {
    console.log("Getting value of " + key);
    console.log(process.env[key]);
}
//Calling the function getEnv
getEnv("key1");


/**
 * 
 * @param {string} key 
 * @param {string} value 
 * //Function to set environment variables.
 */
function setEnv(key, value) {
    fs.readFile(pathToenvFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        var result = parse(data);
        result[key] = value;
        console.log(result);
        fs.writeFile(pathToenvFile, stringify(result), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("File Saved"); // Can be commented or deleted
        })

    });
}
//Calling the function setEnv
setEnv('key1', 'value2');
```

After this run your file using

```
node filename.js
```

You can get your desired output.

Initial .env file

```
# I am a note ...
key1=value1

key2=value2
   # I am a note ...
```

After running program

```
key1=value2
key2=value2
```

Yes your comments gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `envfile` module as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360535/how-to-save-changes-in-env-file-in-node-js).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const envfile = require('envfile');
const envPath = 'pathToEnvFile/.env';
let parsedFile = envfile.parseFileSync(envPath);
parsedFile.NEW_VAR = 'newVariableValue';
fs.writeFileSync(envPath, envfile.stringifySync(parsedFile));
```

Comment: but It does not output  `# note`

Comment: That's due to the module parsing only the actual key-value-pairs. You could manually parse each line, but that seems very error prone. Do you need to set comments programmatically as well?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this：

```js
function setEnv(envText, key, value) {
  if (!envText) {
    return;
  }
  const rp = new RegExp(`${key}=(.*?)\\s`);
  let result = envText.replace(rp, (m, $1) => {
    return m.replace($1, value);
  });
  if (!rp.test(result)) {
    result += `\n${key}=${value}`;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  setEnv(
    `# I am a note ...
  key1=value1
  
  key2=value2
     # I am a note ...`,
    'key1',
    'value2',
  ),
);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
setEnv(
    `# I am a note ...
  key1=value1
  
  key2=value2`,
    'key2',
    'value1',
  )
```

```
setEnv(
    `# I am a note ...
  key1key2=value1
  
  key2=value2`,
    'key2',
    '2222',
  )
```